# Insect ID, Maharashtra, India

Tags: species-identification, entomology, hemiptera

could someone please identify this insect? This photograph was taken in the Western Ghats of Maharashtra, India, near the town of Mahabaleshwar. *Hemiptera* was about as far as I could get using other online guides.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: This is a Coleoptera (beetle), not a Hemiptera (true bug). The [tarsal formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarsal_formula) and overall shape to me suggests [Meloidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blister_beetle).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Due to its coloration, shape and [tarsal formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarsal_formula) (5-5-4) I think that a [Meloidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blister_beetle)(Blister beetle) of the *Pyrota* genus is likely. You can see several examples of species in this genus from a basic [google search](https://www.google.se/search?q=Pyrota&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAmoVChMI38jY_aa1yAIVgg8sCh3e_Az7&biw=1600&bih=773#tbm=isch&q=Pyrota+Meloidae&imgrc=_). Meloidae has about 2500 species world-wide though, and there might be similar species in other genera. Here is an example of [*Pyrota bilineata*](http://bugguide.net/node/view/918423/bgpage), just for comparison.

[image]

(picture from http://bugguide.net/node/view/918423/bgpage)

You probably need somebody more knowledgeable on Indian beetles for a proper species determination though, but hopefully my suggestions can serve as a starting point.

Comment: Thank you! That looks *very* similar to the one in my photograph! Could the difference in the colour of the thorax and legs be attributed to gender or maturity?

Comment: @user19271 I don't think that your species is the same as the one in the picture I attached (*P. bilineata*) - the shape of the head and the thorax coloration is completely different. I only included it to show that your beetle is similar to the *Pyrota* genus.

Comment: @user19271 So, for the record, I don't think my answer should be "accepted", since it doesn't include a likely species ID.

Comment: @fileunderwater Often, ID to species level is impossible with insects, even by experts, certainly based on only photographs. So why shouldn't the answer not be accepted?